# Finding Fourier coefficients $a_n$ of $\ln|\sin(\frac{x}{2})|$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, fourier-series

$\ln|\sin(\frac{x}{2})| = -\ln2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos{nx}}{n}$ where $x\neq2k\pi$ for any integer k.

I'd like to find $a_n$ and here is my stuck.

> \begin{align*} 
> \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\ln|\sin\frac{x}{2}|\cos(nx)dx &= \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln(\sin\frac{x}{2})\cos(nx)dx\\
> &= \frac{2}{\pi}\Big[2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(\sin(x))\cos(2nx)dx\Big]\\
> &= \frac{4}{\pi}[\frac{1}{2n}\sin(2nx)\ln(\sin(x))\Big|_0^\pi - \frac{1}{2n}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(2nx)\cot(x)dx]\\
> &= \frac{4}{\pi}(-\frac{1}{2n}\Big[\sin(2nx)\ln(\sin(x))\Big|_0^\pi - 2n\int_0^\pi \ln(\sin(x))\cos(2nx)dx\Big])\\
> &= \frac{4}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \ln(\sin(x))\cos(2nx)dx
> \end{align*}

And it seems I'm back to square one. Plese give me a hint.

Comment: Do you want to prove that the $\log{|\sin{\frac{x}{2}}|}=-\log{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos{nx}}{n}$ or do you want to explicitly compute the Fourier coefficients?

Comment: for the integral I get $-1/n$ but have not got a method for it yet

Comment: Want to show the coefficient $a_n$ is $\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: @GarethMa It helps, thank you. So I now have $a_n = -\frac{1}{n}$, but the problem obviously shows that it's $\frac{1}{n}$. I don't know what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Recall the Riesz-Fischer theorem (and of course your function is measurable) lets us find the $n$-th Fourier coefficient under the assumption that the Fourier series converges in $L^2$. We can find the $n$-th coefficient, call it $F_n$ by:
\begin{equation*}
F_n = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}dx
\end{equation*}

I understand this integral may be disgusting (and perhaps impossible) to calculate but there may be some simplifications to be had. But something to think about regardless.

Comment: Thank you so much. BTW, this probably is beyond the course I'm now taking. I will study the theorem later.

Comment: Yea no worries! You could still maybe try to plug in f(x) and try to solve but it looks like a terrible integral lol good luck mate

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry if I am confusing you all. The problem was actually a typo. It must be $\ln|\sin(\frac{x}{2})| = −\ln2 - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(nx)}{n}$ and $a_n = -\frac{1}{n}.$

Comment: The edit the question, instead of posting this as an answer.